# Content Editable = true, but only takes one value at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

I'm working on a simple project where I need to make an item in a list editable and then update a JS item to store this.

I'm using Content Editable = True, and it works when I comment out my handleItemEdit function, but when I turn it on, I can only insert one character at a time, forcing me to keep clicking to edit.

Clearly this problem stems from my function, but I can't seem to figure out why.

```js
//Responsible for listening for an edit and updating my object with the new text.

function handleEditItem() {
    $('.js-shopping-item').on('input', function(event) {
        const itemIndex = getItemIndexFromElement(event.currentTarget); //assigning the index of the the editted item to itemIndex
        const updatedItem = STORE.items[itemIndex];
        updatedItem.name = event.currentTarget.innerHTML;
        renderShoppingList();
    });
}


//Returns the index of an Item in the Store
function getItemIndexFromElement(item) {
    const itemIndexString = $(item)
        .closest('.js-item-index-element')
        .attr('data-item-index');
    return parseInt(itemIndexString, 10);

}

//Function responsible for returning the template HTHML to insert into the html.

function generateItemElement(item) {
    let itemIndex = STORE.items.indexOf(item);
    return `
    <li class="js-item-index-element" data-item-index="${itemIndex}">
      <span contentEditable='true' class="shopping-item js-shopping-item ${item.checked ? 'shopping-item__checked' : ''}">${item.name}</span>
      <div class="shopping-item-controls">
        <button class="shopping-item-toggle js-item-toggle">
            <span class="button-label">check</span>
        </button>
        <button class="shopping-item-delete js-item-delete">
            <span class="button-label">delete</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </li>`;
}
```

Comment: Is the function `handleEditItem()` working as expected  in addition?

Comment: Yes, it's updating the obj, but it seems to be updating after each letter pressed.

I'm wondering if it's because I'm calling the renderShoppingList(), which updates the DOM. So I need to delay that until the input is complete. Maybe with a delay? Seems like a hack though.

Comment: I could also just add a "save" button, but not my first choice.

Comment: What do you mean? `$().on('input', ...)`  is always called for each keypress by design